# Is it possible to write a regular expression to check for a few conditions

Tags: c#, regex

I can have the following variants of a `string`:

- `text`
- `[text]` or `[@text]`
- `[OPTIONAL text]` or `[OPTIONAL @text]`

These are all possibilities. Is it possible via regular expression to easily extract the following information:

- What is the `text`,
- Is it surrounded by `[` and `]`,
- Is there an `OPTIONAL` word,
- Is there an `@` before `text`

?

As for what I have done so far, I can

```
 var expressionMatch = Regex.Match(token, "[.*]");
 if (expressionMatch.Success)
 {
      // use now expressionMatch.Value;
      // check in the same way whether OPTIONAL word is there, etc.
 }

 // the input == text, all properties are false
```

But this is ugly. Is there a pretty / clean / simple way to do this?

Comment: I would name the groups.  The groups that don't match will be empty : string pattern = @"(?'preBracket'\[)?(?'optional'OPTIONAL)?\s?(?'ampersand'@)?(?'text'\w+)(?'postBracket'\])?";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[.*]` is not going to do what you want; `[` and `]` are regex metacharacter that enclose a character class; if you want to search for those characters you have to precede them with `\`. `\[.*\]` will require your strings to start with `[` so your first example will not match. `.*` matches any character, including `]` so you will have no way to determine whether your strings end with a `]` or not.

As @jdweng suggested, you should use named groups to capture separate substrings in your pattern. The .NET syntax for named groups is `(?<name>pattern)`. You seem to have five substrings in your pattern:

```
(?<leftBracket>\[?)(?<optional>(OPTIONAL )?)(?<at>\@?)(?<text>[^\]]+)(?<rightBracket>\]?)
```

If this pattern matches, `expressionMatch.Groups["leftBracket"].Value` will contain any left bracket or an empty string. For example, you can determine if the text is surrounded by brackets with:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(expressionMatch.Groups["leftBracket"].Value)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(expressionMatch.Groups["rightBracket"].Value)
```

The rest of the conditions are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

regex = ([)?(\w+\s)?(\@)?(text)]?

This will capture everything you want....

[
OPTIONAL
@
text

Good luck!